# How to pass undefined number of type arguments to generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method that that takes two type argument the first is a class that has a list of items that I pass its type as the second parameter:

```
public static TJCls GetComplexLog<TJCls, TListObj>(int logIds) where TJCls : ISplitList<TListObj>
{
  //here I deserialize the string from DB to TJCls, and deserialize List<string> 
  //from DB to List<TListObj> and set the TJCls's list via the ISplitList's SetList method:
    log.SetList(lst);
}
```

But now the object may have more than one list (unknown number), so is there a way I can pass any number of type arguments, like the notion of `params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable number of type arguments in the syntax you suggest in C# is not possible. That being said, it would be possible to use a seqeunce of type descriptors as follows.

```
public static GetComplexLog(int logIds, IEnumerable<Type> TypeSeq)
{
    // todo
}
```

Using this signature it would be possible to use reflection to do something useful with the type information, even creation of instances is possible. However, static type checks to constrain the types like

```
where TJCls : ISplitList<TListObj>
```

would also be impossible, for type safety at runtime reflection would have to be used and the best that can be done is throwing an exception on violation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass params like arguments to generic type parameters. In your scenario, you can pass TListObj as a method parameter, right?